# Smile detection on server side

Tags: java, angularjs, face-detection

I have to do application that detects your smile. I've decided to do client side with AngularJS, having REST services on server side that are processing image and maybe returning information if smile was detected.

I've found [webcam library](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive) that allows me to take snapshot of user webcam. It works fine by now, but when I'm sending by POST this image to my (local) server, it goes very laggy after a time and one frame has 3-4 s delay. I'm sending frame to server every 600 ms.

I'm asking for ideas to optimize this workflow - maybe my assumptions were bad and application should have another architecture?

Comment: Detects your smile *to what end*? Do you need to find the first appearance of a smile? Does it need to be real-time?

Comment: It would be much better if it was real-time. This application has to count your smiles.

Comment: Then note that your server needs to be processing each frame at least as fast as it's receiving them, i.e. in your case it needs to process the image and return the result within the 600ms before the next one turns up. Is it managing that? Have you done any e.g. profiling to find the bottlenecks?

Comment: I'm just in phase of creating architecture and I don't know how to bite it. My server by now just receives this frame and sends it back - and just this is making so big commotion that it makes me rethink my choices (by the other hand, my device isn't super-ultra-new technology, but still...). Detecting face in client-side isn't best idea in this project, since I'd maybe have desktop application and I have to share services in those projects. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Your application would have to be extremely performant to handle multiple clients all sending images every 600ms and expecting a result before they send the next one without slowing down, or you will have to scale horizontally (by spinning up multiple instances of the service) which can get expensive. This question seems too broad for SO, frankly.

Comment: Can you optimise image being sent and image being processed in subsequent frames. For e.g. after analysing image in first frame find co-ordinates smile and return to front end... In consequent frames just send cropped image of smile to server... Server will also have less load processing cropped smile. Once smile to required metric found, ask client to send full image for that frame.